# How to close a bootstrap modal programmatically using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router, bootstrap-modal, angular-ui-modal

I have a tab view which has a button to open a modal.

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-etis" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addModal">Add</button>
```

The modal is opened via ng-include and by its referencing its name which is 'addModal'

```
<div ng-include=" 'register/individual/views/modal/addBookOfAccounts.html' "></div>
```

Here is my modal code:

```
<!-- Add BOA Modal-->
<ng-form  class="form-etis" name="addBoaForm" method="post">
<div class="modal fade" id="addModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
    aria-labelledby="addIdentificationModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"
    data-backdrop="static">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <div class="modal-title" id="addModalLabel">
                    <div class="no-margin no-padding">
                        <i class="fa fa-book"></i> NEW Book of Account Details
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="pull-right">
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-etis" href=""
        ng-click="ctrl.submitBoaForm()">Ok</a> 
            <a class="btn btn-danger btn-etis" href=""
       data-dismiss="modal" role="button" ng-click="ctrl.closeBoaForm()">Cancel</a>
</div>
```

inside my controller

```
self.submitBoaForm = function () {
                if (self.isBoaFormValid()) {
                    self.bookOfAccountsGrid.data.push(self.bookOfAccounts);
                    self.resetBoaDetails();
                    alert('New BOA Saved');
                } else {
                    console.log('invalid boa form')
                }
            }

            self.closeBoaForm = function () {
                self.showBoaFormValidations = false;
                self.resetBoaDetails();
            };
```

I am able to display the modal just by using data-target. My only problem is on how do i close the modal programmatically inside the submitBoaForm() after the alert method?

Comment: This way of opening modals is too much native.Are you willing to try a different approach to handle bootstrap modals

Comment: actually i've already tried $uibModal: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#%2Fmodal but it just wont work. modal wont open if the animation is set to true. If i set to false it opens but no animation and the background on the page behind the modal is so dark. And when i will use the modalInstance i always get modalInstance undefined. Also it uses 2 controllers on the link i provided, i want to use 1 controller only. @Angular_10

Comment: can you create a plunker demo out of your code